# Debug Adobe Air app on Android without erasing app data

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I need to debug a new version of an Adobe Air app on Android. This has to be not a "clean install", but an actual update so that all the data is preserved from the previous version. Debugging from Animate CC (formerly Flash Professional) automatically deletes the app and data. Is there a way circumvent that?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the app version is higher, export apk and manually install the apk on the device without animate cc.

That works for release builds, debug builds im not sure give it a shot

Comment: I can manually install and start debug apk on a device, but how do I connect it to the debugger? If I select "Debug > Begin Remote Debug Session", nothing happens.

Comment: Make sure your device is on the same wifi network and temp disable firewalls, ip blockers, anything like that. Start remote debud session, then start the app and it should connect as easy as that.

Comment: Somehow this just won't work on my PC.  I just spent an hour trying different settings, but the debugger doesn't connect to the phone. I don't get it. Why starting debug session from PC works flawlessly, but the "remote session" gets stuck in "Waiting for Player to connect...". And yes, the firewall is off.